# Order MYSQL Result by references within a result

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a SQL query that returns an array like this:

```
nr|id    |reference
#1|"1311"|"0"
#2|"1731"|"1260"
#3|"1332"|"1261"
#4|"1312"|"1311"
#5|"1316"|"1312"
#6|"1261"|"1316"
#7|"1260"|"1332"
```

now the problem is that the 2nd column and the 3rd column represent the order of the items, so the correct order of the above array would be

```
1 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 3 - 7 - 2
```

because the 3rd column tells what the id is after which the current item follows.

is there any way to put this into an SQL Query? A solution to sort the array afterwards with PHP would be acceptable, too.

Comment: Are you sure you have the required order correct??

Comment: What are the quotation marks for?

Comment: If it was me, I'd go back to the original query.

Comment: @strawberry: well, I copied the values out of a inspector tool, maybe therefore the quotes are leftover.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: hm, maybe I made a mistake, but it still seems to be ok. the reference just tells what the next id should be

Answer (score 0):

Note that MySQL does not support recursion, so you have to invent it in some way or (better) rearrange your problem so that it doesn't require it. Anyway, just for fun, here's a solution of sorts... (NOTE: I've used NULL to represent orphans)

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET(nr,(
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',a.nr,b.nr,c.nr,d.nr,e.nr,f.nr,g.nr) 
     FROM my_table a 
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table b 
       ON b.reference = a.id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table c 
       ON c.reference = b.id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table d 
       ON d.reference = c.id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table e 
       ON e.reference = d.id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table f 
       ON f.reference = e.id 
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table g 
       ON g.reference = f.id  
     LEFT 
     JOIN my_table h 
       ON h.reference = g.id 
    WHERE a.reference IS NULL
 )) a FROM my_table ORDER BY a;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/347578/1

Comment: thanks - as far as I understand, this means I need to know the number of elements. but these can vary and need not neccessarily be exactly 7..